# save the serial data in text file raspbian

Tags: raspbmc

i want to save my serial data in text file ... how can i i do it ?
i m using the following code:

```
import serial
import time

port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=600, timeout= 3.0)

while True:
        rcv = port.read(5)
        value = (rcv)
        myString = str(value)
        b = open("/var/www/lampu1.txt","a")
        b.write(myString)
        b.close()
```

after execution error occur

```
IOError: [Errno2] No such file or directory: '/var/www/lampu1.txt'
```

Comment: Do you have permission to create files in /var/www or to write to the file /var/www/lampu1.txt ?

Comment: Also, does the file even exist? the `"a"` option at the end of the open statement stands for `append` which means that you are just adding on to the end of the file (I'm sure you knew that, just clarifying.) That said, if there isn't a file, then you won't be able to do said append operation.

Comment: I am pretty sure the `a` of pythons open maps to the `a` of fopen: "append: Open file for output at the end of a file. [...] The file is created if it does not exist."

Comment: What user are you running this as, and what are the permissions of the /var/www/-directory? Also, do you really want to open and close a file in this tight loop?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's abandoned: clarifications were never provided by the OP, and without clarifications it's impossible to know what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save your data to a file then just make these changes:

```
while True:
    rcv = port.read()
    value = (rcv)
    myString = str(value)
    b = open("/home/pi/yourfile.txt", "a")
    b.write(myString)
    b.close()
```

Comment: Where is the difference to the question? I can't see it.